# Cell Edit in Wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am building a wpf application, I have a `DataGrid` where user can edit cells, when I click on a cell for edit, the total text is selected like in this image:

[image: current]

I want the text to be like in this image when the user click on a cell for edit:

[image: wannabe]

Answer (score 1):

**CS**

Implement CustomDataGrid, which inhherites DataGrid

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnPreparingCellForEdit(DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
    {
       base.OnPreparingCellForEdit(e);
       var textbox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
       if (textbox == null) return;
       textbox.Focus();
       textbox.CaretIndex = textbox.Text.Length;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<CustomDataGrid>
</CustomDataGrid>
```

Comment: Is there any other way for doing it

Comment: if you don't want to create custom control, you can create behavior and attached property. Anyway, you must override OnPreparingCellForEdit function.